# How can I use sed to add search pattern in multi-line string after?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have this text in file:

```
<TAG-ONE> multi
 line
 text
<TAG-TWO> multi
 line
 text
```

I want get it:

```
<TAG-ONE> multi
 line
 text
</TAG-ONE>
<TAG-TWO> multi
 line
 text
</TAG-TWO>
```

Please help me end this pattern:

```
sed '/^<[A-Z-]*>/,/^</{s/^<\([A-Z-]*\)>/&\n\1/}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I'm not convinced that parsing XML like file with either sed or awk is a good idea, you can try the following:

```
awk ' /^<.*>/{ if(tag != ""){print tag; }; match($0,"^<(.*)>.*",a); tag= "</" a[1] ">";} {print} END{print tag}' mytextfile
```

The `match()`function in awk allows you to extract regex from string using the array `a`.

The `if` and `END` statements are here to catch the begining and the end of file.

Comment: Good to note that the array argument to `match` is a gawk-only extension. With regular awk you can do something along the lines of `match($0,"^<.*>"); tag= "</" substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1);` instead.

Comment: Thanks `awk '/^<.*>/{if(tag != ""){print tag;}; match($0,"^<[A-Z-]+>"); tag= "</" substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1);} {print} END{print tag}' ` work fine

Answer (score 2):

OR

`awk -v RS="<" 'NR!=1{print "<"$0"</"$1}'`

`RS` is the record separetor. It allows to read a multi line record.

`NR=1` skips the first record (empty in the given example)

The print statement prints the multi line record (the content between 2 `<`) and adds the tag name `$1` which is right after the record separator.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Comment: Better answer than mine. I've put a bit more explanation. The trick with the `RS` is nice!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^</{:a;x;/./s/^<([^>]*>).*/&\n<\/\1/p;x;h;d};H;$!d;ba' file
```

Gather up tag and following lines in the hold space but first check to see if a previous collection exists and if so format the closing tag and print it. Then replace the collection with the start of the next. At end of file, go back and print the last collection etc.